# Customize fields plugin Grails

Tags: grails

I can't figure out how to customize the rendering of fields plugin tags, I have read the plugin official documentation, it says that I have to add "wrappers" files but they don't say [Or I didn't understand] what these files should contain, So can any one help me please? I would like for example to apply a bootstrap class to a table,modify how the form is rendered (for example apply css class to the submit button) ...

Comment: The docs are pretty straight forward. What have you tried? You should share a short .gsp of your try

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have only tried to add the class attribute directly to the f:table but it didn't work.  
The problem i'm facing is that I can't understand how templates actually work, In the documentation they're only talking about widget & field (or that what I have understood): "The f:field tag looks for a template called _wrapper.gsp, the f:widget tag looks for a template called _widget.gsp..." what about the others fields? f:table ? can I have an example of template please? I really want to understand how it works. (Grails 3.1.5)

Comment: I highly recommend watching this video to understand how the Fields plugin works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MFAs4rFSPM

Comment: The voice quality is so bad :/ can you give me an example please? I have found that : https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/issues/203 it's working but the documentation doesn't say anything about putting GPSs in grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp

Answer (score 4):

i struggled for a while with same issue on documentation, older articles reference the **_field.gsp** template but it's been replaced with **_wrapper.gsp** template. I finally got something working:

1. create the following structure:

*views\_fields\default*

2. Create the following files:

*_displayWidget.gsp*

*_displayWrapper.gsp*

*_wrapper.gsp*

3. An example code for rendering the input fields (*_wrapper.gsp*)

`<div class="col-md-12  widget">
        <label class="control-label" for="${property}">${required? '*' : '' } ${label} </label>
        <input id="${property}" name="${property}" placeholder="${label}" type="text" class="form-control form-value" ${required?:''} value="${value}">
</div>`

Additional reading:
https://objectpartners.com/2013/01/16/customizing-grails-scaffolding-and-adding-accessibility-with-the-fields-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

For the `<f:table>` tag I just copied the template content from [here](https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/blob/master/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp), pasted it into grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_table.gsp and then added the bootstrap classes to that as required.